# Is it right or wrong to say "I am still living in my old place"?

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple

Is it right or wrong to use the present continuous in the example below?

> I am still living in my old place.

For some reason "I still live in my old place" sounds so much better to me but two people told me the first construction is OK.

Answer (score 2):

Both of your sentences have the same meaning.  If anything the first

> I am still living in my old place.

places slightly more emphasis on the fact you are still there (after all these years).

Comment: +1 as always. The thing is that the progressive emphasize the process of living, as you have mentioned. The simple present emphasize the fact that   "I still live here" and i didn't move to another place.

Answer (score 0):

We tend to use present continuous is to indicate that we are talking about a temporary situation, and present simple to talk about something more permanent.

If you were talking about rented accommodation, particulary student accommodation where you rent it for a short period like a term or a year, you would definitely use present continuous.

If you were talking about a house that you owned, you would probably used present simple even if you have been there a long time.

As Peter said, you might use present continuous to emphasise that you are still there, particularly if you think that the other person might regard this as surprising: for example, if you still live in a tiny, run-down house and you now have a very well paid job.

Answer (score 0):

The use of "my old place" in both sentences indicates that you are talking of your permanent place of living, not a temporary one.  Besides, the use of the verb live in the present simple and the present continuous indicate the contnuity of the process of living.

So there's no difference in meaning between these sentences, especially in light of the use of still for emphasis and "my old place" in both sentences.

However, as sometimes, we use the present continuous for a temporary situation, the sentence in the present simple is more appropriate and idiomatic.